# How to test a react-bootstrap Modal in React using React Tesing Library(without enzyme)?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-testing-library

I am using Modal from react-bootstrap in my React application, but I am unable to test the Modal.
Is there a way to test Modal using React Testing Library, without enzyme?

Here's my component

```
      <Modal
    show={show}
    onHide={() => handleClose()}
    className="ad-adduser-modal"
    backdrop="static"
    centered
  >
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
     <Modal.Title className="headline4">Login</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Username"
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({username: e.target.value})
            }}
            value={username}
          />
          <input
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({password: e.target.value})
            }}
            value={password}
          />
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button
        onClick={() => login()}
      >
        Login
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
```

Thanks in advance!